# What's the 'Abandoned Sector'?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

Still new in FTL-advanced, first encountered this sector type.

Is it a special sector? does it have stored? What am I to expect in there?

Comment: AFAICT, the site consensus is that [FTL Advanced doesn't need a dedicated tag](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8564/should-a-new-tag-be-created-for-ftl-advanced-edition). Feel free to post there if you feel that the situation has changed enough to warrant re-evaluation.

Comment: @Cloudy Music - mmm, this tag was approved, this is a strange situation.
I do believe that there should be 2 different tags because if posting all in ftl it will cause confusion to players (I didn't play ftl-advanced until today), because you read ftl answer that is related to ftl-advanced.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Advanced edition adds a new alien species, the Lanius. The abandoned sector is rich in encounters with this species, similar to how Mantis are more commonly encountered in the Mantis Homeworlds sector.

Comment: You mean the lanius race?

Comment: Yes, the Lanius.